# Multiple app generation from same codebase

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm searching for some advices or tips about a components oriented project concept (any ideas are welcomed) so the idea is:

- The project is composed by multiple components(each component represent a service).
- Each time I have a new client I should be able to select what component he should have in his app and generate a specific app for him.
- The process of new client app generation shouldn't require strong development knowledge (it would be great if not at all )
- the new app can have specific assets, colors or any other resources.
- All the UI/UX for each app is the same only colors, icons, texts..., can be different.

**My idea about how to develop it**

- Creating a template project as a framework that have all the components logic on it(maybe also creating a framework for each component)
- Each time I need a new app a new target is created the assets that are needed from the template framework will be defined in the target (since the framework can access the target bundle I don't think that will be any problem.
- for the service needed in each target I think about creating a plist for each target with the enabled services).

So is there any advice or tips about a possible better solution?

Comment: This is gonna get taken down by mods soon as you're asking for opinions. Sadly, the people of SO do not want to answer these types of questions as there is no right or wrong answer. I had a previous account taken down for asking 3 questions like this.

Comment: Thanks for the warning did you know a better place where I could ask for opinion ?

Comment: I was down that road once. It's not easy! you are facing many complications, from ownership / profile management, to the fact that Apple doesn't like approving applications that look similar or do the same / similar things. So IMO much better road is developing an SDK, and handling creation of the app as a service request per client. Yes, it would involve some Xcode work, but not too much work if your SDK is easy to integrate with. But it will allow to add uniqueness to each app, as well as solves management and versioning problems.

Comment: I'm assuming Apple is not going to like a developer publishing many similar apps. What you can do is something similar to MySchoolDay, where they have one app, but an administrative user can have you set up a "profile" in the app which will come with its own assets, UI, colours, info, etc. And then the end-user can just select their school and see everything related to it. You can even change the app icon. If it's absolutely necessary for you to have completely separate apps, I don't know any efficient ways to reuse code other than just a simple copy/paste.

Comment: As i know and concluded from the developer guideline the similar apps problem in the app review will no longer be a problem if the app will be published outside the App Store (using an entreprise account). @thiscommunityistoxic as i understand from your comment by pointing to the SDK path you mean the same solution i mentioned above using framework is that right ?

Comment: @SwiftCODA the problem is that each client should have his own app. About the code reuse i think developing the project as a framework could minimise significantly the copy/paste.

Comment: @hach3m I do not know much about frameworks but that could probably work if the apps are going to be very similar. As for publishing, I don't know how well you will be able to get around Apple wanting variety.

Comment: @Hach3m you should have mentioned it's for enterprise accounts. Does every client have their own enterprise account with Apple, or is everyone going to be using your company's? It matters since if you publish app apps under _one_ enterprise account, then doing what you said makes sense. If they all go to different accounts, then I would have a repo per app, and each app uses (yes you can call it) framework. You may even automate generation of the app, but I wouldn't manage all targets under one workspace.

Comment: I had to do so once. Main app with our branch, and each xcassets, colors, translations, etc where set either from compiler flag, or file made part as the target. It really depends on how customisable is the app.

Comment: @thiscommunityistoxic yes i totally forgot to mention the entreprise account. About the account for each client or one account for all, we are actually discussing the two solution and we are trying to determine what would be the best solution for us and our clients. Also I think you're making a good point about the multiple repo if we go for the multiple accounts solution. Thank you.